# Ubuntu 18.04 Wine Office 365

Tags: 18.04, wine, office365

I have seen that people are able to do this, but I cannot get it to work.

I have installed wine 5.0-rc1 because I read that I needed the devel version to be able to run it.

The installer fails with everything I have tried.

Here is output of wine 365.exe (I renamed it because the installer file had a huge name)

```
 wine 365.exe
002b:fixme:msvcrt:_configure_wide_argv (1) stub
002b:fixme:msvcrt:_initialize_wide_environment stub
002b:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({8736922d-e8b2-47eb-8564-23e77e728cf3}, 0x1400ce200, 0x140a10910, 0x140a10910) stub.
002b:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 0, (nil), 0) stub
002b:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022F848 1 C) semi-stub
002b:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022F800 1 C) semi-stub
002b:fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity (0000000000000000,-1,0000000000000000,0000000000000000,0,3,0000000000000000,0,0000000000000000) - stub!
002b:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({a019725f-cff1-47e8-8c9e-8fe2635b6388}, 0x1400ce200, 0x140a109b0, 0x140a109b0) stub.
002b:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({f50d9315-e17e-43c1-8370-3edf6cc057be}, 0x14021d5f0, 0x140a10960, 0x140a10960) stub.
002b:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 0, (nil), 0) stub
002b:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({e6aec961-a5e0-5560-a860-15edd6b70f6c}, 0x140001000, 0x140a10770, 0x140a10790) stub.
002b:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 0x14086ce19, 56) stub
002b:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
002b:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x22edc0 (nil)): stub
002b:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022E580 1 C) semi-stub
002b:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022E1F0 1 C) semi-stub
002b:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022E1E0 1 C) semi-stub
002b:fixme:msi:open_userdata_comp_key only looking at the current user
002b:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x22ebc4 (nil) 0x22ebc0) returning a dummy value (current locale)
002b:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x22ebc4 0x935100 0x22ebc0) returning a dummy value (current locale)
002b:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({559a5658-8100-4d84-b756-0a47a476280c}, 0x1400ce200, 0x140a10720, 0x140a10720) stub.
002b:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({02fd33df-f746-4a10-93a0-2bc6273bc8e4}, 0x1400ce200, 0x140a10e40, 0x140a4d2c0) stub.
002b:fixme:sync:SetWaitableTimerEx (00000000000000B4, 000000000022EC50, 0, 0000000000000000, 0000000000000000, 0000000000000000, 322820) semi-stub
002d:fixme:rawinput:RegisterRawInputDevices Unhandled flags 0x20 for device 2.
002e:fixme:netprofm:list_manager_QueryInterface interface {e19c7100-9709-4db7-9373-e7b518b47086} not implemented
002e:fixme:netprofm:list_manager_QueryInterface interface {e19c7100-9709-4db7-9373-e7b518b47086} not implemented
0031:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW flags 0x2 ignored
0031:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoExW flags 0x2 ignored
0031:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW flags 0x2 ignored
0031:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoExW flags 0x2 ignored
0031:fixme:reg:NtSetInformationKey (0x15c,0x00000002,0x1e6d7c0,0x00000004) stub
wine: Unhandled exception 0xc06d007e in thread 31 at address 000000007104F93D (thread 0031), starting debugger...
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({8736922d-e8b2-47eb-8564-23e77e728cf3}, 0x41d36a, 0x852cc0, 0x852cc0) stub.
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 0, (nil), 0) stub
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0009:fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity (00000000,-1,00000000,00000000,0,3,00000000,0,00000000) - stub!
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({a019725f-cff1-47e8-8c9e-8fe2635b6388}, 0x41d36a, 0x852fc8, 0x852fc8) stub.
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({f50d9315-e17e-43c1-8370-3edf6cc057be}, 0x4f0f57, 0x852cf8, 0x852cf8) stub.
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 0, (nil), 0) stub
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({e6aec961-a5e0-5560-a860-15edd6b70f6c}, 0x401000, 0x852ec8, 0x852ee0) stub.
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 0x806f69, 56) stub
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
0009:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x32f830 (nil)): stub
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0009:fixme:msi:open_userdata_comp_key only looking at the current user
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0009:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x32f654 (nil) 0x32f650) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0009:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x32f654 0xd36dc8 0x32f650) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({559a5658-8100-4d84-b756-0a47a476280c}, 0x41d36a, 0x852e88, 0x852e88) stub.
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({02fd33df-f746-4a10-93a0-2bc6273bc8e4}, 0x41d36a, 0x854228, 0x8724d0) stub.
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0009:fixme:sync:SetWaitableTimerEx (000000DC, 0032F6B0, 0, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000, 322570) semi-stub
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0037:fixme:rawinput:RegisterRawInputDevices Unhandled flags 0x20 for device 2.
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0036:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW flags 0x2 ignored
0036:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoExW flags 0x2 ignored
0036:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW flags 0x2 ignored
0036:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoExW flags 0x2 ignored
0036:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0009:fixme:crypt:CDecodeSignedMsg_GetParam unimplemented for 9
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0034:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
003b:fixme:powershell:wmain stub: L"powershell.exe" L"-NoProfile" L"$package = Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Office.Desktop -allUsers; if (!$package) { $Error.Add(\"Package is not installed\")}; if ($error.Count -eq 0) { Out-File -FilePath 'C:\\users\\smbecker3673\\Temp\\Office.ValidateResult.scratch' -InputObject '1' -Encoding ascii; } else { Out-File -FileP"...
0009:fixme:iphlpapi:CreateSortedAddressPairs (src_list (nil) src_count 0 dst_list 0xdaae60 dst_count 9 options 0 pair_list 0x32e8e8 pair_count 0x32e8e0): stub
0009:fixme:iphlpapi:CreateSortedAddressPairs only mapped IPv4 addresses are supported
0009:fixme:ole:CoEnableCallCancellation (00000000): stub
0045:fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity (0000000000000000,-1,0000000000000000,0000000000000000,1,3,0000000000000000,0,0000000000000000) - stub!
0009:fixme:ole:CoEnableCallCancellation (00000000): stub
0009:fixme:ole:CoEnableCallCancellation (00000000): stub
0009:err:ole:marshal_object Failed to create an IRpcStubBuffer from IPSFactory for {659cdeac-489e-11d9-a9cd-000d56965251} with error 0x80004002
004a:err:ole:ClientIdentity_QueryMultipleInterfaces IRemUnknown_RemQueryInterface failed with error 0x80004002
0009:fixme:ole:CoEnableCallCancellation (00000000): stub
0009:fixme:ole:CoEnableCallCancellation (00000000): stub
004b:fixme:qmgr:BackgroundCopyJob_AddFileWithRanges (000000000062C640)->(L"http://officecdn.microsoft.com/pr/492350f6-3a01-4f97-b9c0-c7c6ddf67d60/Office/Data/v32_16.0.12228.20364.cab" L"C:\\users\\smbecker3673\\Temp\\v32_16.0.12228.20364CheckReachable4068BD4A-770E-4D8C-83AE-4A9F0D0669B5" 1 000000000062E540): stub
0009:fixme:ole:CoEnableCallCancellation (00000000): stub
004a:fixme:qmgr:BackgroundCopyJob_SetPriority (000000000062C640)->(0): stub
0009:fixme:ole:CoEnableCallCancellation (00000000): stub
004b:fixme:qmgr:BackgroundCopyJob_SetNoProgressTimeout (000000000062C640)->(900): stub
0009:fixme:ole:CoEnableCallCancellation (00000000): stub
004a:err:ole:marshal_object Failed to create an IRpcStubBuffer from IPSFactory for {659cdeae-489e-11d9-a9cd-000d56965251} with error 0x80004002
0009:err:ole:ClientIdentity_QueryMultipleInterfaces IRemUnknown_RemQueryInterface failed with error 0x80004002
0009:fixme:wintrust:SOFTPUB_VerifyImageHash Cannot verify hash for pszObjId="1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.28"
0009:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0058:fixme:powershell:wmain stub: L"powershell.exe" L"-NoProfile" L"$package = Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Office.Desktop -allUsers; if (!$package) { $Error.Add(\"Package is not installed\")}; if ($error.Count -eq 0) { Out-File -FilePath 'C:\\users\\smbecker3673\\Temp\\Office.ValidateResult.scratch' -InputObject '1' -Encoding ascii; } else { Out-File -FileP"...
005e:fixme:msvcrt:_configure_wide_argv (1) stub
005e:fixme:msvcrt:_initialize_wide_environment stub
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({8736922d-e8b2-47eb-8564-23e77e728cf3}, 0x1400ce200, 0x140a10910, 0x140a10910) stub.
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 0, (nil), 0) stub
005e:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022F848 1 C) semi-stub
005e:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022F800 1 C) semi-stub
005e:fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity (0000000000000000,-1,0000000000000000,0000000000000000,0,3,0000000000000000,0,0000000000000000) - stub!
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({a019725f-cff1-47e8-8c9e-8fe2635b6388}, 0x1400ce200, 0x140a109b0, 0x140a109b0) stub.
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({f50d9315-e17e-43c1-8370-3edf6cc057be}, 0x14021d5f0, 0x140a10960, 0x140a10960) stub.
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 0, (nil), 0) stub
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({e6aec961-a5e0-5560-a860-15edd6b70f6c}, 0x140001000, 0x140a10770, 0x140a10790) stub.
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 2, 0x14086ce19, 56) stub
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
005e:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x22edc0 (nil)): stub
005e:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022E580 1 C) semi-stub
005e:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022E1F0 1 C) semi-stub
005e:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (000000000022E1E0 1 C) semi-stub
005e:fixme:msi:open_userdata_comp_key only looking at the current user
005e:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x22ebc4 (nil) 0x22ebc0) returning a dummy value (current locale)
005e:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x22ebc4 0x9a6670 0x22ebc0) returning a dummy value (current locale)
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({559a5658-8100-4d84-b756-0a47a476280c}, 0x1400ce200, 0x140a10720, 0x140a10720) stub.
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({02fd33df-f746-4a10-93a0-2bc6273bc8e4}, 0x1400ce200, 0x140a10e40, 0x140a4d2c0) stub.
005e:fixme:sync:SetWaitableTimerEx (00000000000000E4, 000000000022EC50, 0, 0000000000000000, 0000000000000000, 0000000000000000, 321820) semi-stub
0061:fixme:netprofm:list_manager_QueryInterface interface {e19c7100-9709-4db7-9373-e7b518b47086} not implemented
0060:fixme:rawinput:RegisterRawInputDevices Unhandled flags 0x20 for device 2.
0061:fixme:netprofm:list_manager_QueryInterface interface {e19c7100-9709-4db7-9373-e7b518b47086} not implemented
005e:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW flags 0x2 ignored
005e:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoExW flags 0x2 ignored
005e:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoSizeExW flags 0x2 ignored
005e:fixme:ver:GetFileVersionInfoExW flags 0x2 ignored
005e:fixme:reg:NtSetInformationKey (0x16c,0x00000002,0x22de40,0x00000004) stub
005e:fixme:rpc:RpcServerRegisterIf3 Unsupported SecurityDescriptor argument.
0066:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventRegister ({8736922d-e8b2-47eb-8564-23e77e728cf3}, 0x2243b80, 0x242b360, 0x242b360) stub.
0066:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventSetInformation (deadbeef, 0, (nil), 0) stub
0066:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x219c610 (nil)): stub
0066:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x219c524 (nil) 0x219c520) returning a dummy value (current locale)
0066:fixme:nls:get_dummy_preferred_ui_language (0x8 0x219c524 0x92e170 0x219c520) returning a dummy value (current locale)
001a:fixme:appbar:handle_appbarmessage SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, hwnd=0000000000000000): stub
0037:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x1005e,{245d8541-3943-4422-b025-13a784f679b7},0): stub
0037:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x1005e,{5d3e9a59-e9d5-4b00-a6bd-ff34ff516548},0): stub
0037:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x1005e,{a7ad8041-b45a-4cae-87a3-eecbb468a9e1},0): stub
0037:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x1005e,{98a7f580-01f7-48aa-9c0f-44352c29e5c0},0): stub
0037:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x1005e,{02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea},0): stub
0037:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x1005e,{3c0f4548-c03f-4c4d-b9f2-237ede686376},0): stub
0060:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x3006c,{245d8541-3943-4422-b025-13a784f679b7},0): stub
0060:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x3006c,{5d3e9a59-e9d5-4b00-a6bd-ff34ff516548},0): stub
0060:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x3006c,{a7ad8041-b45a-4cae-87a3-eecbb468a9e1},0): stub
0060:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x3006c,{98a7f580-01f7-48aa-9c0f-44352c29e5c0},0): stub
0060:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x3006c,{02731015-4510-4526-99e6-e5a17ebd1aea},0): stub
0060:fixme:win:RegisterPowerSettingNotification (0x3006c,{3c0f4548-c03f-4c4d-b9f2-237ede686376},0): stub
006e:fixme:combase:RoGetActivationFactory (L"Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation", {5074f851-950d-4165-9c15-365619481eea}, 0000000000942508): semi-stub
006e:err:combase:RoGetActivationFactory Failed to find library for L"Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation"
0061:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0000000001C4E6D0 1 C) semi-stub
0061:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0000000001C4E770 1 C) semi-stub
0061:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0000000001C4E3A0 1 C) semi-stub
0061:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0061:fixme:combase:RoGetActivationFactory (L"Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId.OnlineIdSystemAuthenticator", {85047792-f634-41e3-96a4-5164e902c740}, 0000000001C4F160): semi-stub
0061:err:combase:RoGetActivationFactory Failed to find library for L"Windows.Security.Authentication.OnlineId.OnlineIdSystemAuthenticator"
0061:fixme:msvcp:_Locinfo__Locinfo_ctor_cat_cstr (0000000001C4EEE0 1 C) semi-stub
0060:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0060:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0060:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0060:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0060:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0060:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
005e:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
0037:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0037:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0037:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0037:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0037:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0037:fixme:win:UnregisterPowerSettingNotification (0xdeadbeef): stub
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
0009:fixme:ntdll:EtwEventUnregister (deadbeef) stub.
0009:fixme:kernelbase:AppPolicyGetProcessTerminationMethod FFFFFFFA, 0032FEAC
```

It starts a progress bar. Then I get a Microsoft error that doesn't give me any info. Looking it up, it's related to network firewall or anti virus issues.

Any help would be awesome. I have wiped my Windows 10 PC and installed Ubuntu 18.04, due to the fact every "Feature Update" causes it to lock completely (Safe Mode and all) and requires a full reinstall everytime so far. I have some experience with Linux as I run a few servers, CentOS, Ubuntu, Raspbian, but those have been mostly copy and paste stuff into terminals, with a few learning scripting situations.

Comment: Offhand, with all those `fixme:`, and `err:` messages, I'd guess `wine` doesn't provide several of the Windows functions needed by `365.exe`. If you can't get back to where you saw it was done, it won't work. Have you investigtated `libreoffice`?

Comment: The posts that showed it working had no info at all other than it worked. Yes libre is installed by default on ubuntu, I can use it if I absolutely need to, absolutely being the keyword.

Comment: Ended up getting crossover. It installed a bunch of .net stuff and required fonts.